# Parsing Trouble || Try to select a checkbox than push the button and than get info

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a Telegram bot (don't mind it, I'm testing everything in another file in the console right now, and I'll refactor this later) that sends random movies and I'm confused.
I want to add some variables, like a completely random movie or a random movie based on the selected genre. I have problems with the second one, I can get full random movie, it's works fine, but I don't understand why the genres don't work. I think I'm trying to get data from html wrong.

*And I know my dict - geners is crooked (different register and e.t.c. , I change it later), I tested manually with 1 - 3 values*

**main_pars.py:**

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


user_input = input("Genre: ")


class ParsSettings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/chance/"
        self.url_for_img = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru/"

        self.response = requests.get(self.url)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        self.user_genre_key = None
        self.genres = {
            'genre_1750 ': 'Anime', 'genre_22': 'biography',
            'genre_3': 'action movie', 'genre_13': 'Western',
            'genre_19': 'Military', 'genre_17': 'Detective',
            'genre_456': 'Kids', 'genre_12': 'documentary',
            'genre_8': 'Drama', 'genre_23': 'History',
            'genre_6': 'Comedy', 'genre_15': 'short film',
            'genre_16': 'Crime', 'genre_7': 'Melodrama',
            'genre_21': 'Music', 'genre_14': 'Cartoon',
            'genre_9 ': 'Musical', 'genre_10': 'Adventure',
            'genre_11': 'Family', 'genre_24': 'Sport',
            'genre_4': 'Thriller', 'genre_1': 'Horror',
            'genre_2': 'Fantastic', 'genre_18': 'Film-Noir',
            'genre_5': 'Fantasy'
        }


class GetRandomMovieData(ParsSettings):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.poster_div = None
        self.poster_img_href = None
        self.poster_img = None

        self.film_name_div = None
        self.film_name = None

        self.film_genre_div = None
        self.film_genre = None

        self.film_rating_div = None
        self.film_rating_imb = None

        self.film_desc_div = None
        self.film_desc = None

        self.driver.get(self.url)

        self.list = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "genreListTitle")
        self.button = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")

        self.new_html = None
        self.soup = None

    def find_user_genre(self, genre):
        """
        dict genre: keys == class <li> in HTML || values == genres
        :return: genre key by user input genre, like: Anime: genre_1750
        """

        for key in self.genres:
            if self.genres[key] == genre:
                self.user_genre_key = key
                print("User Input:", user_input)
                print("Genre Key: ", self.user_genre_key)
                return self.user_genre_key
        print("No Same Gener")
        return None

    def get_rnd_movie(self):
        self.button.click()
        self.new_html = self.driver.page_source
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.new_html, "lxml")
        self.driver.quit()
        return self.soup

    def get_rnd_gener_movie(self):
        self.find_user_genre(user_input)
        self.list.click()

        self.checkbox = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, self.user_genre_key)
        if self.checkbox:
            self.user_genre_key = self.user_genre_key
            self.checkbox.click()
            self.button.click()
            self.new_html = self.driver.page_source
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.new_html, "lxml")
            self.driver.quit()
            return self.soup
        else:
            print("No Same Genre")
            return None

    def get_full_rnd_movie_data(self, genre=False):
        self.soup = None

        if not genre:
            self.soup = self.get_rnd_movie()
        elif genre:
            self.soup = self.get_rnd_gener_movie()

        self.poster_div = self.soup.find("div", class_="poster")
        self.poster_img_href = self.poster_div.find("img")["src"]
        self.poster_img = self.url_for_img + self.poster_img_href

        self.film_name_div = self.soup.find("div", class_="filmName")
        self.film_name = self.film_name_div.find("a").text

        self.film_genre_div = self.soup.find("div", class_="gray")
        self.film_genre = self.film_genre_div.text.strip()

        self.film_rating_div = self.soup.find("div", class_="rating")
        self.film_rating_imb = self.film_rating_div.text.strip()

        self.film_desc_div = self.soup.find("div", class_="syn")
        self.film_desc = self.film_desc_div.text.strip()


movie_data = GetRandomMovieData()

# For now just switch False - for get full random movie and True - for genre random movie
movie_data.get_full_rnd_movie_data(True)

print("Movie Name:", movie_data.film_name)
print("Genre:", movie_data.film_genre)
print("Rating:", movie_data.film_rating_imb)
print("Description:", movie_data.film_desc)
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\Iwlj4s\Desktop\pm\telegramMovieBot\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:

\Users\Iwlj4s\Desktop\pm\telegramMovieBot\getMovies\main_pars.py 

Genre: Anime

User Input: Anime

Genre Key:  genre_1750 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Iwlj4s\Desktop\pm\telegramMovieBot\getMovies\main_pars.py", line 130, in <module>

    movie_data.get_full_rnd_movie_data(True)

  File "C:\Users\Iwlj4s\Desktop\pm\telegramMovieBot\getMovies\main_pars.py", line 111, in 

get_full_rnd_movie_data

    self.poster_img_href = self.poster_div.find("img")["src"]

                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

**html block where user selecting genre:**

```
<div class="left_select">
                <div onclick="KP.filter.openSelect('genreList');" id="genreListTitle" class="selectCustom">выберите жанры</div>
                <ul onmouseout="KP.filter.selectBlockClose=false;" onmouseover="KP.filter.selectBlockClose=true;" class="genreList selectList" id="genreList" style="display: block;">
                    
                        <li class="genre_1750 selectItem"><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="KP.filter.toggleCheckbox('genre', this);" data-name="аниме" value="1750" name="m_act[genre][]"> аниме</label></li>
                    
                        <li class="genre_22 selectItem"><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="KP.filter.toggleCheckbox('genre', this);" data-name="биография" value="22" name="m_act[genre][]"> биография</label></li>
                    
                        <li class="genre_3 selectItem"><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="KP.filter.toggleCheckbox('genre', this);" data-name="боевик" value="3" name="m_act[genre][]"> боевик</label></li>
                    
                        <li class="genre_13 selectItem"><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="KP.filter.toggleCheckbox('genre', this);" data-name="вестерн" value="13" name="m_act[genre][]"> вестерн</label></li>
```

I except I get a random movie by genre like I get just random movie, but something wrong and I don't know what is it.

Please tell me what I do wrong and how I can fix that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm idiot. Driver worked too fast, I need just add time.sleep()

```
    def get_rnd_gener_movie(self):
        self.find_user_genre(user_input)
        self.list.click()
        
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//input[@value='{self.user_genre_key}']").click()
        
        time.sleep(5)
        self.button.click()
        
        self.new_html = self.driver.page_source
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.new_html, "lxml")
        
        self.driver.quit()
        return self.soup
```

and now I search genre by value

```
'22': 'Biography'
```

```
  <li class="genre_22 selectItem"><label><input type="checkbox" onchange="KP.filter.toggleCheckbox('genre', this);" data-name="биография" value="22" name="m_act[genre][]"> биография</label></li>
```